# Создание сниппета в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, сниппет

Как настроить автозамену любого текста в Visual Studio Code?

Например, чтобы при вводе "hello" + <kbd>Enter</kbd> этот текст заменялся на "hello world".

Answer (score 4):

Не увидел ваш вопрос в ленте сразу, но вы затронули интересную тему сниппетов. Описание, примеры использования и более глубокое погружение можно найти в [оф. доке (англ.)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

### Как создать собственный сниппет?

1. Определить где он вам нужен. Либо создать глобально (этот вариант опишу), либо для конкретного проекта
2. Откройте `Command palett` (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (macOS), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (windows), либо <kbd>F1</kbd>) и в строку введите следующее: `snippets`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Выберите `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`
4. Выберите `New Global Snippets file...`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Придумайте имя для файла и вбейте его
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. У вас откроется `json` - файл и в него добавьте примерно такое

```json
{
    "Snippet Number One":{
        "prefix": ["hel", "ho"],
        "body": "Hello everybody",
        "description": "It's just for ruSO"
    }
}
```

- `Snippet number One` -> имя сниппета
- `prefix` -> шаблоны для ввода (может быть в виде *одного* строкового значения или *списка* строковых значений)
- `body` -> чем заполнится по итогу
- `description` -> описание

Сохраните файл и можете использовать.

### Как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> получаем
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]